# Applying subproblem technique to permutations with grouping

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, permutations

I am trying to apply overlapping subproblems and dynamic programming to permutations.

Say, we have a set of $n$ elements in a string. Each of these elements could be a $1$ or a $0$.

Given some string, I am trying to count the number of valid permutations- where a valid arrangement is defined as an ordering with no $1$ that stands alone from other 1s.

Example input string: $0101$

Example of valid arrangements: $1100, 0011, 0110$

Not valid: $0101, 1010, 1001$

EXPECTED OUTPUT: $3$

For example:

Say our input string contains four 1s and two 0s.

I suppose my difficulty is coming with defining the sub-problem. I initially thought I could set up a string with only the $0$ elements with slots/bins in between. $[ ] 0 [ ] 0 [] $, and then continue to use combinatorics to compute the number of additional arrangements possible with each 1 added in.

The first 1: 0 possibilities, because it will never have a 1 to accompany it.

Adding the 2nd 1: 3 possibilities, because the pair can go in either of the 3 slots.

Adding the 3rd 1: 0 new possibilities, because it must go with the other 2 ones, wherever they are.

Adding the 4th 1: We have enough to make 2 groups of $1$s now... here is where I start getting unsure. I'd think it would be an additional 3 possibilities. $\binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{2} = 6$ total

Would anyone have an idea if I'm on the wrong track, or if not, how to proceed? This approach doesn't seem like it works for larger values. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem basically asks for number of possible strings which contain groups of consecutive 1s, where each group has more than one 1 digit. This solution can be directly obtained using the recurrence relation for [Associated Stirling numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Associated_Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Answer (score 0):

The subproblems can be broken down as follows.

```
f0 :- Number of available 0s.

f1 :- Number of available 1s.

ld :- The last digit of the string generated till now.

dp[f1][f0+f1][0] = dp[f1][f0+f1-1][0] + dp[f1-1][f0+f1-1][1]

dp[f1][f0+f1][1] = dp[f1-2][f0+f1-2][0] + dp[f1-1][f0+f1-1][1]
```

which basically boils down to,

Say at any step the string is `S0`

then `S011` and `S00` are valid as well.

Similarly,

if the string is `S1` then `S11` and `S10` are valid as well.

The following code solves the given problem recursively.

```
def rec(f0,f1,stn): # Frequency of 0,Frequency of 1, List to store generated output
  if f0==0 and f1==0:
    print(''.join(stn))
    return -1;
  if len(stn)==0 or stn[-1]=='0':
    if f0>0:
      rec(f0-1,f1,[x for x in stn]+['0'])
    if f1>1:
      rec(f0,f1-2,[x for x in stn]+['1','1'])
  else:
    if f1>0:
      rec(f0,f1-1,[x for x in stn]+['1'])
    if f0>0:
      rec(f0-1,f1,[x for x in stn]+['0'])

rec(4,4,[])
```

You can easily solve the overlapping subproblems issue by using a dp-table along with the propagation rules listed above.

Output of the code for a string with `4 1s` and `4 0s`:-

```
00001111
00011110
00011011
00111100
00110011
00110110
01111000
01100011
01100110
01101100
11110000
11000011
11000110
11001100
11011000
```